# differentiating between tracking and normal cookies

Tags: http, cookies

My question sounds pretty dumb but I have no idea how can i distinguish between the two. I am looking for any methods possible to write a small soft piece to do this.
Thank you

Comment: What makes you think there is a difference?

Comment: What does C++ and C have to do with *cookies*? I don't remember those in the standard C libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can't distinguish between tracking cookies and other cookies from a client perspective. Tracking cookies is something that's done by the server, not a specific type of cookie.

If you want more details on tracking cookies, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Tracking) has a good description.